# How can I style the zsh completion section headers?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

In my screenshot, the section headers ("recent branches", "local head", etc.) are visually indistinguishable from the completion suggestions.

`compinstall` doesn't seem to be able to change the styling.

How can I, for example, set the section headers in bold or invert fg/bg colors?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`info zsh format`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-format_002c-completion-style) (you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent).

You can set the `format` `zstyle` for completions:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format '%K{blue}%F{yellow}Completing %d:%k%f'
```

Would show the completion headers as something like `Completing recent branches:` in yellow over a blue background.

You'll find it in the `compinstall` menus under:

```
3.  Styles for changing the way completions are displayed and inserted.
[...]
1.  Change appearance of completion lists:  allows descriptions of
    completions to appear and sorting of different types of completions.
[...]
1.  Print a message above completion lists describing what is being
    completed.
[...]
You can set a string which is displayed on a line above the list of matches
for completions.  A `%d' in this string will be replaced by a brief
description of the type of completion.  For example, if you set the
string to `Completing %d', and type ^D to show a list of files, the line
`Completing files' will appear above that list.  Enter an empty line to
turn this feature off.  If you enter something which doesn't include `%d',
then `%d' will be appended.  Quotation will be added automatically.

description>
```

You'll find that `compinstall` does set the style as `zstyle ':completion:*' format`. That sets the format for *all* kinds of completions (files, directories, filters...). You can also set different styles for different categories (see the first argument passed to `_description` in `grep -rw _descriptions $fpath`):

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*director*' format '%F{blue}%BCompleting %d:%b%f'
zstyle ':completion:*:*file*' format '%F{magenta}%BCompleting %d:%b%f'

# fallback:
zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format '%BCompleting %d:%b'
```

Though you'll find those *tags* (`files`, `directories`...) are not always use consistently by all completers.

Comment: Thanks. A remark: `info zsh format` does not work for me, it points to the start page `info zsh`.

Comment: @FelixDombek, you may need to install a `zsh-doc` package or equivalent. Some systems don't install the doc in info format by default. I've added a link to where `info zsh format` should take you. You'll find the same information in the man pages, but the man format is really not appropriate for a manual this big IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in https://github.com/solnic/dotfiles/blob/master/home/zsh/completion.zsh.

The relevant excerpt is

```
// needs 'autoload -U colors && colors' 

zstyle ':completion:*:descriptions' format "%{${fg_bold[magenta]}%}= %d =%{$reset_color%}"
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `colors` function here. You can use the `%K{colour}`, `%F{colour}` like in prompt expansion (which allows you to use true-colours (possibly  via `zsh/nearcolor` if your terminal doesn't support true-colour).